# How to implement a command line of ffmpeg with ffmpeg static lib?

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg

I need a simple ffmpeg conversion task to be done inside an application:

```
ffmpeg -i input_file.m4v -vcodec copy -acodec copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb output_file.ts
```

This works well using the terminal. I've successfully compiled ffmpeg's static lib. Some examples work perfectly, that means the lib is working. How do I implement the behaviour of the above command line with this library?

I looked into ffmpeg.c. But there is so much code inside that it took me hours to get an idea on how it works. Finally I still don't really understand the whole structure.

I would be very happy if someone could help me understanding how to use the library to do the very same what the example command line does. (At the end I just want to transmux mp4 files to ts files without reencoding)

Thanks in advance

Jack

Comment: Did you look in `doc/examples` in the FFmpeg source code?